# How do I select entries through an intermediary table relationship?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

This probably has a really obvious answer, but I am drawing a blank somehow. I have three tables, let's say they are called:

```
People   
Addresses  
AddressDetails
```

I am using Entity Framework (so above are models with the relationships properly set up). I am trying to select the data with a typical EF LINQ query (doesn't matter whether method or query syntax).

People and Addresses are many-to-many. Addresses and AddressDetails are one-to-one(/zero). I need to select all entries from AddressDetails which correspond to a particular PersonId. I know the connection is there since I can select all Addresses where PersonId = n, and each Address only has one AddressDetails entry, but how do I do it properly?

---

I tried the following:

```
            var details = 
                from p in db.People
                where p.Id = n
                from a in p.Addresses
                from ad in a.Details
                select ad;
```

Visual Studio highlights "Details" in a.Details and gives the following:

> 'API.Models.Addresses' does not contain a definition for 'API.Models.Details"...

I am fairly certain this is basically EF telling me it doesn't see a relationship. I did verify that the one-to-one is there. Any ideas? Could it be that EF doesn't see it because there is no FK in the Addresses table? (The Addresses PK is the Details PK/FK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var details = 
    from p in People
    where p.Id = n
    from a in p.Addresses
    from ad in a.Details
    select ad;
```

FYI: A good reference for LINQ is [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Ran into an issue, edited post, take a look if you want / have time. Completely understand if not.

Answer (score 1):

This could be another way to achieve what you are looking for:

```
var id=1;
var query= context.People
                  .Where(p=>p.Id==id)
                  .SelectMany(p=>p.Addresses.Select(a=>a.AddressDetails));
```

The key here is use the `SelectMany` method which flattens the resulting `AddressDetails` sequences into one sequence.

In case you have disabled [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOff), call the `Include` method to eager load the related navigation properties as part of the query:

```
var id=1;
var query= context.People
                  .Include(p=>p.Addresses.Select(a=>a.AddressDetails))
                  .Where(p=>p.Id==id)
                  .SelectMany(p=>p.Addresses.Select(a=>a.AddressDetails));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying out both this and dmeet's answer.

Comment: Hmm, edited the post. With dmeel's example EF sees Addresses but not AddressDetails, with your example it doesn't see Addresses. I feel like I need to double check the relationships between models. Will come back to accept one of the replies when I get it working.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't it - my model names aren't what I gave in the example, just made for an easy example when asking the Q. Anyway, I am fairly certain the issue is on my end. Will keep trying, ty again.